# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.dll on client PC

Tags: vb.net, dll, exchangewebservices

I know there are more articles of this on the internet i think i found them all but still cant solve my problem for the client PC's.

i have a windows forms project installed on a server that every client PC's useses. I added the reference 2 my project and installed the EwsManagedApi on my own computer for testing and changed the location of where 2 find the references to the folder that EwsManagedApi installs.

When i am trying to use the module that uses the Exchange Web Services i get the error.

I only have the shotcut on my pc and the application is running good. i know the reference path is good i checked this more than 5 times. but when i just copy the dll to my folder where the shortcut is it is working good. what do i have to do to get the dll from the server where the aopplication is installed.

Tanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the Microsoft Exchange WebServices API 2.0 in every client
to be sure you have all the necesary assemblies.

[Microsoft Exchange Web Services Managed API 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35371)

In addition, check out the the server version. Maybe it is 64 bits and the
clients are running 32 bits.

Comment: But i have the application i use installed on the server than they shud be able 2 read the file from the server am i right. if the API webservice is installed on the server they use to run the application. the reference .DLL is also installed on the server.

Comment: Maybe the EWS its using some of the assemblies that are located in  C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\ and the client has not that assemblies. I recommend you to install the sdk on the clients .I'm sure your problems should dissapear.

Comment: I now have the solution i need to delete the old applcation i whas using on the server and install the new version than the client will find the references that i supplied but i dont understand wy becase i only changed the reference path? Tanx For your help Carlos